# why does the class_exists function return false?

Tags: php

In the following script I check the `class_exists` function. What is the scope of this function ? It returns `false` for this script when I test for this class.

```
<?php
namespace my;
class Tester {      
    public function check() {
        $classname = 'Tester';
        if(class_exists($classname)) {
            echo "class exists ! <br />";
        } else {
            echo "class doesn't exist ! <br />";
        }
    }
}   

$obj = new Tester();
$obj->check();
```

*Output : class doesn't exist*

Comment: Have you tried calling it outside the class definition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Tester` isn't in the global namespace. It's in the `my` namespace.

Both of these will work:

```
$classname = '\my\Tester';
$classname = 'my\Tester';
```

Comment: so `class_exists` checks in the global namespace ?

Comment: Well, it checks the class name, and the class name you passed was for a class in the global namespace.